# How to add an UIImageView in Google street view sdk for ios

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-street-view

```
@IBOutlet weak var getout: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var legstreet: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var viewStreett: GMSPanoramaView!
var panoramaNear: CLLocationCoordinate2D!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    panoramaNear = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(30.274262, -97.752371)
    //var panoramaNear = self.tmpString
    var panoView = GMSPanoramaView.panoramaWithFrame(CGRectZero,
        nearCoordinate:panoramaNear)        
    self.viewStreett = panoView
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

When I write like this, the street view can't show. and I have to revise
`self.viewStreett = panoView` to `self.view = panoView.` But at this time UIImageView disappear. So my question is how to add UIImageView into streetview and don't disturb the use of street view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `viewStreet` will be a loading `GMSPanoramaView`, because it has no coordinate. So you can not make a loading `GMSPanoramaView` equals to your `panoView`(`viewStreet = panoView` wont work).

Instead, you can change the type of `viewStreet` to `UIView`, now it will behavior like a container view of your `panoView`. Then you can do `viewStreet.addSubview(panoView)` to add your `panoView` to the container.

Sample Code:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var viewStreet: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sampleImageView: UIImageView!
    var panoView: GMSPanoramaView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let panoramaNear = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(30.274262, -97.752371)

        panoView = GMSPanoramaView.panoramaWithFrame(CGRectZero,
            nearCoordinate:panoramaNear)

        viewStreet.addSubview(panoView)
        viewStreet.sendSubviewToBack(panoView)

        let equalWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: panoView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: viewStreet, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let equalHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: panoView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: viewStreet, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: panoView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: viewStreet, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let left = NSLayoutConstraint(item: panoView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: viewStreet, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        panoView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([equalWidth, equalHeight, top, left])
    }
```

If you are using AutoLayout in your app, you should add width, height, top and left constraints to your `panoView`.

You can view sample app in [this GitHub page](https://github.com/ziyang0621/GMPanoramaViewSwift).

In the simulator screenshot below, I simply add a marker image on top of the `panoView`.
[image]